# deleting a if statements using ASTParser from a given .java file

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have a requirement of deleting all if conditions from a given .java source file. How can I perform this using  a ASTParser in JDT.

```
public static void selectDecision(x,y)
{
     if()
     {
       /////////
     }
     else 
     {
       //////////
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASTRewrite (org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite)